# Python import error from one script to another

Tags: python, variables, scripting

I have a serie of scripts that run one after the other.  In one of them i try to import variable from the first one.  The problem is that when that variable is imported the whole first script gets executed. 
In the first script i have:

```
various commands
x = result of these commands
```

On the other script i have:

```
from first script import x
various other commands 
y = z + x
```

When this line is called the first script get executed..
Why is that?  Is this technically wrong??

Comment: python is a scripting language. as juliend said your first script has lines not enclosed in functions so they will be executed. you should have only one main program in the entirety of your program. if you want to run the first script and get the value of x, you should encapsulate the calculations for x in functions and call those functions in your main script.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is your first script, which shoud encapsulate the code in functions/classes, and call the main function, say `run()`, only if the script is called directly, with

```
if __main__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

See [__main__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) .